# Some users email does not return from Facebook API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook application and i use the JavaScript JDK.

Im requesting the email permission well:

For new users i redirect to authorization window:

```
top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + APP_ID + '&scope=email&redirect_uri=XXX';
```

And then trying to fetch it:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            console.log(response.email);
        }
    }
 }
```

For existing users (in case their email is undefined) i even tried re request the email permission and re fetching it:

```
FB.login(function(response){
    if(response.status == 'connected'){
            FB.api('/me?fields=email,id',  function(response) {
                  console.log(response.email);
              });
    }
},{scope: 'email'});
```

The problem is that for some user i get the email in the response of /me and for other its undefined.
What can be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This issue is causing me a lot of trouble.  Have you come across any advancement or workarounds for this??

Comment: I am also facing same issue ,if you have any solutions for that please let me know..

Answer (score 5):

This is not a solution to the problem, But I have recently worked around it to make it work.

Since, all facebook users are assigned an email address by facebook with the id : 
`[username]@facebook.com`  , I decided to use this email if the request didnt return email address of the user.

i.e.

```
$email = isset($fb_user["email"])?$fb_user["email"]:$fb_user["username"] . "@facebook.com";
```

Again, This is not the solution, just a workaround.

Hope this helps.